# Licensing LGPL software commercially

Tags: licensing, gpl

We have a mobile app software and we distribute it with LGPL v3. It uses other 2 components licensed under LGPL-v3 and MIT. For our own code, we are have the full ownership (i.e. nobody else have made any contribution)

Later we created a modified version and customized it for a company and it will be distributing their own version of this mobile App. But this company doesn't want to publish the sources. How do we give the rights to this company to distribute the App without sources ?  We did not modify the other components that our App uses, only our own code.

A simple mail saying "Hey, it is ok , you can distribute the binaries of our app without any problem, you have our permission" doesn't look very formal. So, how is this done legally?

What documents do we have to provide or what changes do we have to make in order to do this correctly?

Comment: This question might be a better fit for the [opensource.se] site. If you ask there, please also describe (1) whether you are the sole copyright holder or whether you used some parts from third parties under a GPL license, and (2) whether the customized version by the company will only be used internally or whether they will distribute the app.

Comment: @amon , I have made edits, do you think you can answer it?

Comment: If you are the sole copyright holder of all GPL-covered parts, the GPL is irrelevant. Go to your company's legal counsel and draft a contract with the other company that grants them a non-exclusive license under whatever terms you negotiated.